# Is "quack" a non-finite form of the verb in "What does the duck do? Quack."?

Tags: nonfinite-verbs

> Q. What does the duck do?
>
> A. Quack.

Do you take "quack" there to be a non-finite form of the verb?

Edit: I removed Tinfoil Hat's very apt edit only because I wanted to stick with animals, and not bring in moms and baking.

> Q. What does the kangaroo do?
> A. Hop!
>
> Q. What does a mouse do?
> A. Scurry.

Comment: To quack: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quack

Comment: The question does not normally use _do_. When asking a child what noise an animal makes, one uses _go_, not _do_. The answer is _ducks go "quack"_, in which case "quack" is not a verb but an onomatopoeic sound, like "moo" or "bow-wow". Call them any part of speech you like.

Comment: @JohnLawler - what does “go” mean in that case

Comment: Not sure about your question. Third person singular sounds more natural "What does the duck do?" "Quacks." "What does the child do in the park?" "Plays football." In such a case you can drop the pronoun, as is common in casual speech: "What did you do?" "Went to the park and played football." With a general question it's possible to answer in the plural "What does the duck do?" "Ducks quack." Whether there is a formal grammar-book answer for this, I don't know.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ducks and quacking. *Q: What does your mom do? A: Bake.* What is *bake* here? It's not the result of answer ellipsis, nor is it a noise.

Comment: Bad examples make for bad questions. In those cases, it's an infinitive, the object complement of _do_.

Comment: @JohnLawler — Yes, it seems it's a bare infinite. But what do you mean by object complement? Like this? *A: My mom does bake.*

Comment: An object complement is a noun clause that appears as the object of some verb.  [There are several kinds](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), governed by the verb. The verb _do_, like modal auxiliaries, must be followed by an infinitive complement. In _My mom  does bake_, I would consider _bake_ the main verb and _do_ an emphatic auxiliary, which, nevertheless, must be followed by an infinitive of the next verb, the same way _have_ in the Perfect must be followed by the past participle of the next verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler — But we don't have an emphatic *do* situation here, so why is the bare infinitive used in the elliptical answer? What's curious is that in the answer ellipsis for *Q. What do you do? A. Bake*, *bake* does not seem to be a bare infinitive, but rather a first-person conjugation and a proper (parallel) answer ellipsis for *I bake*.

Comment: I would disagree that the single word "Quacks" is how a native speaker would answer the question "What does a duck do?" The finite verb all by its lonesome is not an idiomatic response there.

Comment: @John Lawler: So the finite verb as complement is a kind of noun clause that can occupy the same kind of slot as *What*?

Comment: @TRomano — Of course that's how it would be answered, but why? Compare *Q: What does a duck do? A: Quack* (bare infinitive, idiomatic) with *Q: What do ducks do? A: Quack* (conjugated verb minus *ducks*, answer ellipsis).

Comment: @TinfoilHat.  Not sure I agree that ellipsis explains the latter.

Comment: @TRomano — Would you argue that it's a bare infinitive in both cases?

Comment: @TinfoilHat:  Why should the number of the subject affect the *do* verb object complement?

Comment: @TRomano — It wouldn't, if that's really what's happening. *Quack does a duck. Quack do ducks.*

Comment: @TRomano: Arguably it's a bit pointless trying to analyze the syntax of one-word answers in such contexts. But so far as I'm concerned, valid responses to *What does your mom do?* include ***Bake*** (unmarked infinitive, *What she does is bake*) and ***Bakes*** (reduced from *My mom bakes*) and ***Baking*** (gerund noun, *The activity she does is baking*). The less common highly informal *What does your mom **go**?* might feasibly elicit a response along the lines of *[My mom goes] "If you don't eat your dinner you can't have any pudding!"*

Comment: @gio In answer to "what does 'go' mean", see transitive verb definition 7 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go)

Comment: @TinfoilHat  What a frog does do is hop.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  There are any number of *valid* answers to questions like the one presented in my posting.  I was curious how other people understood the form presented.

Comment: @Tim — When you keep what was a question-auxiliary-*do* in your answer, you turn it into an emphatic *do*: *What a frog **does** do is hop.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat:  A case of ellipsis?  *[A frog does] hop!*

Comment: @TRomano — I think you were on the right track with "... verb is a kind of noun clause that can occupy the same kind of slot as *What*?" See [Movement first, ellipsis second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_ellipsis#Movement_first,_ellipsis_second) at Wikipedia's Answer ellipsis. *What did you say? Nothing <-- I said.* "The object *nothing* is moved to the left out of the constituent S in such a manner that S (the lower S) can then be elided." *What does a frog do? Hop <-- a frog does.*

Comment: Could we stop commenting and answer the question, please?

Comment: @AndrewLeach — It appears no one has an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The most proper way to answer a question like this is with a full sentence containing a subject and verb:

> Q. What does the duck do?
>
> A. It quacks [or flies, floats, etc.].

But simple responses like this are often abbreviated because the form of the question makes "it" understood and redundant. In this case, you can simply omit the pronoun:

> A. Quacks.

or omit the pronoun and replace the conjugated verb with a bare infinitive.

> A. Quack.

Comment: We're not dealing with "the proper way" but with language as spoken by native speakers.

Comment: That was my point -- in normal speach you can abbreviate.

Comment: I don't think any native speaker would answer *What does the duck do?* with *Quacks.* It would be *Quack.*